# Has Warlock existed in any of Moira's previous lives?

Tags: marvel, x-men, new-mutants, house-of-x

**(Note. The title is enough to ask the basic question - I'm explaining the rationale behind it at some length here before asking it in full.)**

In Marvel's ["House of X"/"Powers of X"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_X) limited series, there is a major retcon. We discover that Moira MacTaggert is a reincarnating mutant, and has lived nine lives before the timeline we know.

In most of these, humanity has committed anti-mutant genocide in Charles Xavier's lifetime, with the development of AI/robotics technology (in particular the Sentinels) giving them the means to do this. Moira has become radicalised through her repeated attempts to stop this genocide, both against humanity and against these technologies. This has led to mutant leaders encouraging human dependency on Krakoan biochemistry, so as to stunt further technological development.

In [one of Moira's previous lives](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-TRN753), [far-future humanity](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Homo_novissima) have summoned a machine-consciousness collective, the [Phalanx](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Phalanx_(Race)). The humans wish to upload their consciousness and join the Phalanx. We learn that the Phalanx created the [Technarchy](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Technarchy) ([Warlock](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Warlock_(Technarch)_(Earth-616))'s people) and use the Technarchy to wipe out civilisations and species they deem unworthy. The merged human/Phalanx would be able to cross into alternate universes/timelines, including Moira's other lives. The human leaders have been using their machines, not necessarily to kill the mutants, but to buy time while they artificially evolved even further than *Homo superior*.

Moira has spent all of her current lifetime working behind the scenes to establish Krakoan plant technology as a means, not just of stunting human technological development, but possibly even of forcing major changes to the nature of humanity itself, while assembling mutantkind on its own nation-state island.

In HoX/PoX, this came into the open. We saw Karima/Omega Sentinel working with humans against mutants, possibly having been shunned and outcast by those she fought alongside, due to her part-Sentinel cyborg nature. We note that Doug has to conceal Warlock's existence, making it seem as though a techno-organic infection of his arm is all that remains. Possibly this is because Warlock would now be in danger.

And yet... Warlock is a mutant Technarch, in that he has compassion. He values friendship. We have not seen any evidence of such a thing in the Phalanx or Technarchy in Moira's previous lives. Warlock has been able to change the nature of his father, the [Magus](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Magus_(Technarch)_(Earth-616)) - the most powerful member of the Technarchy. And a side effect of the conflict between Warlock and Magus was that the Technarchy on the planet Kvch were nearly wiped out. The Phalanx Covenant storyline happened because Phalanx could be created from a captured Warlock, and these Phalanx were able to summon the Technarchy.

Warlock's existence offers an alternate possibility - that the Technarchy, and the Phalanx, could change. That through him and the viruses he/they rely on, compassion, empathy and tolerance could become part of these machine species, changing their nature. The Phalanx of this universe could potentially become creatures who did not routinely commit the genocide of races deemed "unworthy" and the assimilation of the rest.

This seems incompatible with Moira's anti-AI stance, as her previous lives have involved war with humans and attempts to stop advanced robotic technology. She knows about the Technarchy and Phalanx and seems to see no hope of the Phalanx being anything but the final, lethal threat.

And yet, in this timeline, when Warlock arrived, she and Xavier acted as though they did not recognise this being or his species.

[image: Moira examines Warlock]

They made Warlock welcome on Earth, sheltered him in the X-Mansion, allowed him to make friends with the New Mutants...

[image: Xavier meets Warlock]

[image: Xavier shakes hands with Warlock]

[image: Xavier's thoughts on Warlock]

Xavier, in the fight between Warlock and Magus in new Mutants #50, even told Warlock that the point wasn't to defeat Magus. The brutal, survival-of-the-fittest, Sith-rule-of-Two-like war between fathers and sons, with only the fittest surviving, would not be stopped by killing Magus. Warlock *had* to find a way to strike a blow against *that*.

[image: Xavier talks to Warlock]

This doesn't seem consistent - UNLESS Warlock did not exist in Moira's previous lives. He may be a random mutation that has only occurred in this timeline, yielding a new hope for the embattled mutants. Or the mutations that created him may have been artificially induced somehow, in some form of stealth attack on the Technarchy we haven't been shown. It may even be part of Moira's plan - or Xavier's - to create a being that could change the very nature of the ultimate robot enemy. To make it their friend, instead of defeating it.

("Friend", according to Ship, being a concept that meant nothing to the Technarchy hitherto.)

**(And finally, the question.)**

I've looked through the *[House](https://www.marvel.com/comics/series/26338/house_of_x_2019)*/*[Powers](https://www.marvel.com/comics/series/26340/powers_of_x_2019)* issues on [Marvel Unlimited](https://www.marvel.com/comics/series/2055/new_mutants_1983_-_1991), looking for any scene from Moira's previous lives in which Warlock appears or is mentioned in panel, since this would disprove my theory. I haven't been able to find any. Perhaps I've missed one.

***Have any scenes, or pieces of dialogue, or anything else in any X title, demonstrated the existence of Warlock in any of the timelines created by Moira's past lives? Especially Timeline 4, which is very similar to Earth-616?***

Comment: I'm not sure how [Danger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danger_(comics)), the Danger Room AI who became sentient, would fit into this. I haven't been able to find any post-HoxPox appearances of her, and I don't know when her last appearance in the comics was.